# How to load dependencies from another fat JAR or from external sources?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I managed to split my Spring Boot fat JAR in 2 thinner fat JARs, (one with the app and one with dependencies).

Now, I'm trying to run the app, but I'm unable to load the dependencies from inside the fat jar.

So far, I tried:

```
java -jar app.jar -cp "deps.jar"
java -jar app.jar -cp "deps.jar/BOOT-INF/lib"
```

I also tried decompressing the JAR and tried to load it

```
java -Dloader.path="jars:deps/BOOT-INF/lib" -jar app.jar
java -jar app.jar -cp "deps/BOOT-INF/lib"
```

But no progress.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your goal in splitting this up?

Comment: Not having to upload stable dependencies... I tried the "Spring Boot thin launcher" but it doesnt work properly with multimodule projects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 2: Decompress the fat JAR and read classes**

If you are working with Spring Boot, you need to change the type of loader in the MANIFEST file and include the path of the libraries.

If you are using Gradle, during the fat JAR generation, you can add:

```
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher'
    attributes 'Class-Path': 'deps/BOOT-INF/lib'
  }
```

And after you can run the app with:

```
java -Dloader.path="jars:deps/BOOT-INF/lib" -jar app.jar
```